# Smartphone audio streaming - mp3 to stereo

Tags: mp3, stereo

There is a feature in modern smartphones where you can have a mp3 file in your phone and stream it to a bluetooth device for playback. My question is, how does this work?

Since it is mp3, there is only one channel streaming right? (one data stream)

Then the device decodes it and produces the analog voltage levels.

But usually, they use stereo mode.
In mp3 file format, how does the data stream convert into two different files (two channels - for stereo mode)

Comment: MP3 is a single stream of data that encodes two (or more) channels of analog audio.

Comment: You have two hands, yet only one body, yes? So it is with MP3.

Comment: A very simplified example would be a file where the odd words are the voltage level for the left channel and the even words for the voltage level for the right channel. This is basically what a raw audio (WAV) file looks like. An MP3 file is just this, but compressed.